# Facebook sharing through UIActivityViewController doesnot show all activity items in share dialog

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, facebook-share

I have added title, description,image and a URL link to client page in activity items of UIActivityViewController, but the share dialog shows only the image.
It used to work fine before, has there been any update in UIActivityViewController or facebook share dialog recently?

Comment: I am facing same issue. any luck with issue?

Comment: Nope...didn't find any solution to it as yet.

Answer (score 1):

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#ios-integration:

Use of the iOS share sheet is subject to Facebook Platform Policy, including section 2.3 which states that apps may not pre-fill. In the context of the share sheet, this means apps may not pre-fill the share sheet's initialText field with content that wasn't entered by people earlier in their use of the app.

Looks like we are out of luck.